# How much to store luggage at SFO for 24 hours?

Tags: luggage-storage, sfo

Say a medium-ish sized bag that weighs 50 lbs (23 kg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no clear price information mentioned on [the airport website](http://www.flysfo.com/faqs). The easiest thing to do will be to call or email them. Their website provides this information:

> Baggage storage is exclusively available at the Airport Travel Agency,
>   located on the Departures/Ticketing Level of the International
>   Terminal, near the entrance to Gates G91-G102. **The Airport Travel
>   Agency is open daily from 7:00 a.m. to 11:00 p.m.** No reservations are
>   required for baggage storage. All baggage is x-rayed prior to storage.
>   **Rates are assessed per each 24 hour period that an article is in
>   storage (articles in storage for less than 24 hours will be subject to
>   the 24 hour rate), and vary according to the size of the object.**
>   Please contact the Airport Travel Agency at 650.877.0422 or
>   CF.Airport@gmail.com for additional information.

[SF To Do](http://www.sftodo.com/sanfranciscoairport.html) says that the typical rates vary from $15 to $35 whereas the pricing on the [Airport Travel Agency Website](http://www.airporttravelagency.org/price_list.pdf) is quite ambiguous and seems to not agree with the same. I would assume that your size luggage would cost approximately $25 but the best solution is to just ask via email.

> SFO offers only one staffed location where you can store baggage. 
>   Airport Travel Agency, located in the Departures/Ticketing Level of
>   the International Terminal, is near the entrance to Gates G91-G102. 
>   **It offers storage for $15 to $35 per day depending on the size of
>   items you are storing.**

Answer (score 6):

I just called the Airport Travel Agency.  Bottom line: you won't know the price until you get there.  But figure $35 per bag, per day.  In our case the cost would be $70 for two bags for 10 hours.  So, it's cheaper for us to just to keep the rental car for an extra day.

Answer (score 1):

They finally put the price online:

https://www.airporttravelagency.org/airport-travel-services/

We have a five-hour layover before an international flight, so we can't checkin our luggage. Figuring with four checked-in bags and two cabin bags, we may end up with $170 luggage storage bill. Instead, we decided to rent a car to the city with our bags for $72. Beats being at the airport for 5 hours.

Comment: This works well, but keep in mind that [car break-ins are a significant problem](https://www.nbcbayarea.com/news/local/Breaking-Point-475109113.html) in San Francisco, especially in tourist areas. Do not leave your luggage (or any other belongings) unattended in the car, as a smashed window and missing luggage would really put a damper on your travel plans.